# How to use Angular 2 with lite-server and wamp

Tags: apache, angular, angular-cli

I'm starting using Angular 2, installed with angular-cli and I'm having some issues, starting with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44551089/call-php-file-with-angular4-and-cli-return-page-not-found) (already answered), but it led me into another problem.

Since I'm using PhpMyAdmin to manage my databases, I'm using Wamp, on default port 80. Angular is running on the lite-server on port 4000. Both in localhost.

The problem happens when I need to call a PHP file to process data on the database.

When using directly on Wamp, I have a `.htaccess` file with mod.rewrite configuration to handle this case, which is not the case in here, since I'm running Angular on lite-server. I'm also not able to run Angular on Wamp because of the bundle process it does to insert all the script tags on the index file, etc...

So the problem is: I can't call the PHP file, because I'll be running into 2 possible issues:

- Call a file without mod.rewrite, which is going to treat it as a URL and will redirect to my not found state.
- Call the PHP at the default localhost, which will not be found since the file isn't there, but on a folder inside the root project.

I've found 2 solutions for this, bot none of them seems reasonable:

- Move just the PHP files folder to the localhost:80 root: The project is going to be split everywhere, if there is other project than it's not going to work.
- Build the Angular project every time there is code change, so I can use it with WAMP server, but then again, it's very time consuming, since it will bundle everything in production mode every time.

Is there a way I can fix this and run the code properly?

I can either resolve this domain request or adapt the angular-cli to just bundle everything while running on Apache server.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: To me, it seems like you are trying to run two independent applications as one. Is this your intent?

Comment: @GrahamS. Yes, but actually no, I'd prefer to run all in a single server. I prefer to run all in wamp, since I already manage database there, other projects already run on wamp, etc.. But since Angular-cli does this compilation automatic, I don't know how to integrate this with Wamp.

Comment: I would say keep the Angular 2 project completely separate. It's possible to put them on the same server, but I don't believe WAMP is geared for serving up an Angular project (not that you can't hack it out). If you're trying to keep them on the same server, it would appear to me that you would need to put the Angular project to serve on port 80 and the PHP backend on a different port. This is so that if you were to visit the site using a fully qualified domain name, say http://example.com, you would be served the Angular app, which should perform async requests to the PHP app on other port.

Comment: @GrahamS. This is kind of confusing to me, because If I'm going to call the php file to connect to database, don't it need to be in the same directory? I mean, i know we can call from other domains, etc.. But this is a simple project. So, what would be the solution?

Comment: No worries, was very confusing to me at first too. So the thing with Angular 2 is that it's not just a framework anymore (as compared to Angular 1), it's more a *platform* that is really meant to be standalone. The Angular 2 app will emit web service calls to a ***remote*** service and retrieve the returned data as JSON. In a nutshell, the Angular 2 app is basically just spitting out AJAX calls any time it needs to read, save, update, or delete data. You PHP script should basically behave as the "remote" web service.

Comment: And your PHP script should be able to receive the request, perform whatever action it has to with the database, and return a response. So your PHP script is basically an API.

Comment: @GrahamS. I'm kind of making it work! Do you any advice on how to organize the project on this case? If I try to put the `api` folder inside the `src` folder I get `500 internal server error`, but if I keep on the project root folder, I can make it work.

Comment: Probably best to keep it in the project root. I believe Angular 2 goes through the `src/` directory recursively to transpile `.ts` files into javascript files in your `public/` directory, so putting a `.php` file in there might cause a problem which I suspect might be why you get the 500.

Comment: I usually even keep the PHP project completely outside of the Angular project and just run that in WAMP. You could technically put the Angular 2 project in whatever directory on your computer that you want to, be able to run `ng serve`, and still be able to make the calls to your PHP backend as long as the PHP server is up and running.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146708/discussion-between-celsomtrindade-and-graham-s).

Comment: Sounds good. I am heading home from my day job and I'll join when I'm home.